# получение нового массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив из N элементов. Нужно каждый элемент разделить на 2 и вывести новый элемент. Код на javascript.

```
let arr = [2,4,6];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
alert(arr[i]/2);
}
```

Только тут у меня каждый элемент выходит по одному раз, то есть сначала 1 потом 2 и потом, а нужно что вывелся новый массив элементов 1,2,3.
Как это реализовать?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать новый массив и заполнить его через цикл. alert в конце цикла.

```js
let arr = [2,4,6];
let newArr = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
  newArr.push(arr[i]/2);
}

alert(newArr)
```

Вот более красивый код:

```js
const arr = [2, 4, 6]
const newArr = []

for (item of arr)
  newArr.push(item / 2)

alert(newArr)
```

Вот через метод map:

```js
const arr = [2, 4, 6]
const newArr = arr.map(item => item / 2)

alert(newArr)
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Для получения нового массива на основе старого можно использовать метод [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let arr = [2, 4, 6];
let arr2 = arr.map(el => el / 2);
console.log(arr2);
```